# A particle moves along the curve $y=mx^a + c$ with a constant speed $v$. Find the velocity at x=n (in $i cap, j cap$) and acceleration at x=n

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, integration

A particle moves along the curve $y=mx^a + c$ with a constant speed $v$. Find the velocity at x=n (in $i cap, j cap$) and acceleration at x=n.

I tried this question as:
I found out the slope of curve by differentiating which gives tanθ and we know the resultant is $v$ of both $ vectors(components of velocity)$ so by trigonometry i can find values of i cap, j cap. Is it the correct way to proceed this the of problem?
Also i am having problems with acceleration and can you guide me through it?

Comment: There is a simple formatting system for text (e.g. *italics*) and there is no need to use Mathjax for most text formatting.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely problem solving approach your method may serve you with the correct answer, but you need to understand that slope i.e. dy/dx is actually (velocity)y/(velocity)x .This can be simply understood by differentiation of implicit functions as velocity is dx/dt. Having understood that, for acceleration you can use the relation that : acceleration = v.dv/dx , where v = velocity and x= position . Thus with the given equation of curve you wont have difficulty solving this equation.
If you need any clarifications please revert back.
CHEERS!!!